# Unable to install xlsx package on R version 3.1.3

Tags: r, install.packages

When I run `install.packages("xlsx")` I get this:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Zahra/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning: unable to access index for repository https://rweb.quant.ku.edu/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
>   Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
>   Warning message:
>   package ‘xlsx’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)

I already tried `setRepositories` and a couple of more things but no luck! I appreciate any comments

Comment: Can you install other packages? Are you sure your internet connection isn't being blocked? Have you tried other CRAN mirrors (`chooseCRANmirror()`)?

Comment: The [second url](http://www.rforge.net/bin/windows/contrib/3.1) is broken; however, the [first url](https://rweb.quant.ku.edu/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/) indeed includes `xlsx_0.5.7` ([the most recent version listed on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf)), and I was able to download it directly from there.

Comment: I have not been able to install any other package, xlsReadWrite,perl,...

Comment: And yes my internet connection works

Comment: You have `install.packages("xslx")` - do you mean `xlsx`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my own answer! I figured the problem was that for installing all those packages, the required package was "rjava" that couldn't be loaded. The reason was the fact I am using a 64-bit OS and R version but do not have Java installed with the same architecture.I downloaded Java 64-bit(Windows Offline (64-bit)) from this page: https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp After that just reloaded the xlsx package and it worked