# fail to install R package xlsx

Tags: r, r-xlsx

Since the newest version of `xlsx` is still in source format I used

```
install.packages("xlsx", type = "source")
```

I have encountered the following issue when intalling xlsx.

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
      call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
      error: unable to load shared object 'C:/.../R-3.5.0/library/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
      LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Since I do not have the admin access I have manually set my java path

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre8/bin/')
```

Can the reason be the fact that I have 64bit OS but R and java are both 32bit?

Comment: Yes if they dont share the same architecture, thats a problem. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31392778/3682794)

Comment: although not addressing the failure would openxlsx be useful. I think it removes the dependecny on java and you should be able to achieve many of things you want done,

`Description Simplifies the creation of Excel .xlsx files by providing a high level interface to writing, styling and editing worksheets. Through the use of 'Rcpp', read/write times are comparable to the 'xlsx' and 'XLConnect' packages with the added benefit of removing the dependency on Java.`

Comment: The `readxl` package also enables reading excel files without external dependencies.

Comment: @SeGa Even though I have aligned R with Java to the same architecture (32bit)?

Comment: @user1317221_G The problem I am facing is that it is in middle of a larger development, which means I do not really have the freedom to choose which package I can use.

Comment: I am not exactly sure. But could you try aligning R / Java with 64bit?

Comment: @SeGa Unfortunately, I can't, because I do not have admin access on my account.